# Counterexample for binary search trees can be always joined in logarithmic time

Tags: algorithm, merge, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

The question is, basically, **what would be an example of two balanced binary search trees that cannot be merged in logarithmic time?**

Motivation:

Suppose we have two balanced binary search trees T1 and T2 with *n* and *m* nodes respectively. Their depth is logarithmic (*O(log n)* and *O(log m)* respectively). Suppose n <= m.

If the intervals of values of T1 and T2 do not overlap, i.e., max T1 < min T2 (or max T2 < min T1), joining those trees can be really efficient (O(log m)) if we use, e.g., Splay trees or Treaps.

Otherwise, the best algorithm I am aware of is a linear O(n + m) algorithm (inorder traversal of both trees followed by merging the values and the creation of a new balanced tree).

This is much worse than logarithmic but (while doodling around) I could not find two trees of size n (for some arbitrary large n) where it would be necessary to use this algorithm.

Comment: This can never be proved by an *example*, because time complexity is about **asymptotic** behaviour.

Comment: @trincot If the example would consist of a description of how to construct two such trees of size n for arbitrarily large n, then this would suffice.

Comment: OK, I would not call this "an example of **two** binary search trees". It seems you are now referring to families of arbitrary large trees, and that is fine of course.

Comment: @trincot I agree that a general construction is indeed a one-parameter family of pairs of such trees, but I think changing the question to include this would not make the question any clearer.

Comment: cf. https://walkccc.me/CLRS/Chap13/Problems/13-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make one a balanced binary tree of length `m` of the even numbers in the range `2..2m`.  Make the other a balanced binary tree of length `m` of the odd numbers in the range `1..2m-1`.

The merged binary tree needs to wind up with `O(m)` nodes with values from the one tree with children are from the other tree.  And therefore you cannot merge without constructing at least `O(m)` new nodes, which takes `O(m)` time.

Comment: @MooingDuck There isn't a lesser vs greater tree here. There are even and odd trees. An even value has to go between any two odds, and an odd between any two evens. Therefore any internal node with a value from one tree must have at least one child from the other. In the case where value ranges don't overlap, the OP indicates 2 strategies that are logarithmic.

Comment: I saw "the intervals of values of T1 and T2 do not overlap" in the question, and misread the rest of the sentence. My mistake.

Comment: I tried with this one, but was missing the claim "the merged binary tree needs to wind up with `O(m)` nodes with values from the one tree with children are from the other tree". It is not obvious (to me), but it's true: the inorder traversal of the merged tree needs to give us the numbers 1, 2, ..., 2m. The inorder traversal from a node whose left child is a leaf, is LEFT, NODE, ... (and similarly for the right-leaf case: ..., NODE, RIGHT). Thus, every leaf needs to have a parent of the opposite parity. There are `O(m)` leaves and that concludes the proof. Thank you.